# Importing cufflinks with conda in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, conda

I import plotly via conda with no problems, have dropped down to v3.1.0 from v4.10. Then import cufflinks via the conda prompt using CONDA INSTALL -C FORGE CUFFLINKS-PY (also tried other channels).  In Notebook, no issues with importing plotly but using IMPORT CUFFLINKS AS CL returns the following error: AttributeError: module 'plotly.files' has no attribute 'FILE_CONTENT'

have tried solving by switching out from python plotly version 4.10 to 3.1.0.  Also tried other channels when importing cufflinks in the conda hub.

CODE:

```
import pandas as pds
import numpy as npy
from plotly import tools
import plotly.offline as offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from plotly import __version__

from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot

import cufflinks as cl
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [`cufflinks-py` is an old version of the package](https://github.com/conda-forge/cufflinks-py-feedstock/issues/9). The reason it's letting you install it is that it doesn't appear to have a proper upper bound on the version number (only `plotly >=2.0.0`), whereas it likely only works for `plotly >=2.0.0,< 3.0.0`.  You should remove this:

```
conda remove cufflinks-py
```

and install the newer version of the package listed under `python-cufflinks`, i.e.,:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-cufflinks
```

which shows requirements for Plotly 3.*.

Comment: BTW, I [submitted a PR](https://github.com/conda-forge/cufflinks-py-feedstock/pull/10) so others shouldn't hit this problem in the future.

Comment: Okay, this is now merged and live on the channel.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and in my case this is more to do with operating system.  On Windows - the Dhirschfeld and Avishapiro channels seem to be a better choice.  Will also try the newer version of conda-forge.  Thanks.